# Validation failed for query for method JPQL

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, spring-boot

I am implementing a query which return output in custom object. With my implementation, I am getting an error:

> "method public abstract java.util.List org.degs.repository.ConsolidateresponseRepository.transactions()!"

JPQL Repository code:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT new org.degs.beans.ConsolidateResDB(DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%d-%m-%Y') AS transdate,IFNULL(COUNT(orderreqid),0),IFNULL(COUNT(failamount),0),IFNULL(SUM(amount),0),IFNULL(SUM(successamount),0),IFNULL(SUM(failamount),0),IFNULL(COUNT(successcount),0)) FROM Consolidateresponse GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%d-%m-%Y') ORDER BY ts DESC")
public List<ConsolidateResDB> transactions();
```

`ConsolidateResDB` bean:

```
public class ConsolidateResDB {
    String transdate;
    long total;
    long failcount;
    double totalamount; double successamount;
    double failamount;
    long successcount;
}
```

I have already handled null values in the query itself and getting normal output if I run the same query in mysql db terminal, but while implementing in JPA and Spring Boot still receiving the `NullPointerException`
error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'crRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consolidateresponseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.degs.repository.ConsolidateresponseRepository.transactions()!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]
at org.degs.SbipgMisApplication.main(SbipgMisApplication.java:16) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.2.RELEASE.jar:1.5.2.RELEASE]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consolidateresponseRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.degs.repository.ConsolidateresponseRepository.transactions()!
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 24 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List org.degs.repository.ConsolidateresponseRepository.transactions()!
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:92) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:62) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:72) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:53) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:144) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:212) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:77) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:436) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:221) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:277) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:263) ~[spring-data-commons-1.13.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:101) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
... 34 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.NameGenerator.generateColumnNames(NameGenerator.java:27) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.util.SessionFactoryHelper.generateColumnNames(SessionFactoryHelper.java:418) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeColumnNames(SelectClause.java:267) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.finishInitialization(SelectClause.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SelectClause.initializeExplicitSelectClause(SelectClause.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.useSelectClause(HqlSqlWalker.java:920) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.processQuery(HqlSqlWalker.java:688) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:673) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:309) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:257) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:262) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:190) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:142) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:76) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:150) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:302) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:240) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1894) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:291) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_121]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:347) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.createQuery(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:86) ~[spring-data-jpa-1.11.1.RELEASE.jar:na]
... 47 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Invalid JPQL. There is no such function "DATE_FORMAT". See the JPA spec

Comment: You are mixing JPQL and SQL here that is not going to work.

Answer (score 115, accepted):

You have tell Spring to treat that query as native one. Otherwise it will try to validate it according to the JPA specification.

Try:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> transactions();
```

Keep in mind that cannot use the NEW operator syntax in this case and you would have to deal with result as an array of `Object`.

**Alternatively**

If you want to use map the results directly to a POJO class you would have to (assuming that you are using JPA 2.1+):

**1)** Define the mapping:

```
@SqlResultSetMapping(
    name="transactionsMapping",
    classes={
        @ConstructorResult(
            targetClass=ConsolidateResDB.class,
            columns={
                @ColumnResult(name="transdate"),
                @ColumnResult(name="orderreqid")
                // further mappings ...
            }
        )
    }
)
```

**2)** Define a native query

```
@NamedNativeQuery(name="transactions"
    , query="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(ts, '%d-%m-%Y') AS transdate, IFNULL(COUNT(orderreqid),0) ... ")
```

**3)** Define this method in the `CrudRepository` without the `@Query` annotation:

```
public List<ConsolidateResDB> transactions();
```

Comment: @Query(value = "SELECT ...", nativeQuery = true)
public List<Object[]> transactions();

Answer (score 4):

**For Spring Data `2.0.5` and above,**

After trying solution by Maciej my code started complaining `"Got different size of tuples and aliases".` 
To fix the issue in latest release we need to add

```
@Query(<Entity.FunctionName>, nativeQuery=true).
```

This made my code work e2e.

Answer (score 3):

For me it was (well not exactly the same code but you get the idea):

```
@Query("SELECT e FROM TheEntity e WHERE e.stuff = :stuff")
List<SomeEntity> findSomething(@Param("stuff") String someStr);
```

And don't forget the Entity:

```
@Entity(name = "TheEntity")
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue, below worked for me.

```
@Query(value = "select NEW org.degs.beans.ConsolidateResDB(DATE_FORMAT(c.ts, '%d-%m-%Y') ,IFNULL(COUNT(c.orderreqid),0),IFNULL(COUNT(c.failamount),0),IFNULL(SUM(c.amount),0),IFNULL(SUM(c.successamount),0),IFNULL(SUM(c.failamount),0),IFNULL(COUNT(c.successcount),0)) FROM Consolidateresponse c GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(c.ts, '%d-%m-%Y') ORDER BY c.ts DESC") 
public List<ConsolidateResDB> transactions();
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and I din't want to use native query.

Solved it by removing the INNER JOIN clause.

```
  // Will not work if relations between entity classes are not defined properly.
  @Query(value = "SELECT d FROM Animal a "
      + "INNER JOIN Dog d ON a.id = d.animalId "
      + "WHERE d.name = ?1")
```

Here is the working one.

```
  // Works fine. (NO INNER JOIN)
  @Query(value = "SELECT d FROM Animal a, Dog d "
      + "WHERE a.id = d.animalId "
      + "WHERE d.name = ?1")
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I wasn't trying to return output in a custom object. But I was getting this error as described in the question:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query 
...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

In my case, my code was like this:

```java
public interface MyRepository extends CrudRepository<MyDAO, MyDAOPK> {
   @Query("select MyDAO from MyDAO")
   List<MyDAO> getAll();
}
```

What I had to do was remove the `SELECT`.

```java
@Query("from MyDAO")
List<MyDAO> getAll();
```

Credit to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49817396/validation-failed-for-query-for-method-public-abstract-java-util-list) for a clue.

Also I was able to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61395847/1042151) elsewhere, to use a custom object to return results, as the original question asked about.