# Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have a basic SpringBoot app. using Spring Initializer, JPA, embedded Tomcat, Thymeleaf template engine, and package as an executable JAR file.
The version of SpringBoot is 2.0.1.RELEASE. 
I've created a class repository that extends from CrudRepository with this method

```
@Query("select us.priceAlertsTapas.tapa from User us left join us.priceAlertsTapas  pat left join pat.tapa tapa where pat.priceAlert = ?1")
    List<Tapa> tapasByUserPriceAlert (PriceAlert pa);
```

But when I init the project I got this error:

```
Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List



    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:93)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.<init>(SimpleJpaQuery.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromMethodWithQueryString(JpaQueryFactory.java:76)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryFactory.fromQueryAnnotation(JpaQueryFactory.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$DeclaredQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:139)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$CreateIfNotFoundQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryLookupStrategy$AbstractQueryLookupStrategy.resolveQuery(JpaQueryLookupStrategy.java:79)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lookupQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:553)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$mapMethodsToQuery$1(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:546)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Iterator.forEachRemaining(Iterator.java:116)
    at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.forEachRemaining(Collections.java:1049)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:1801)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:481)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.mapMethodsToQuery(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:548)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.lambda$new$0(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at java.util.Optional.map(Optional.java:215)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.<init>(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:538)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:317)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.lambda$afterPropertiesSet$3(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:287)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.getNullable(Lazy.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.util.Lazy.get(Lazy.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.afterPropertiesSet(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:290)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JpaRepositoryFactoryBean.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698)
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.HqlSqlWalker.createFromJoinElement(HqlSqlWalker.java:424)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.joinElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3931)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3717)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromElementList(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:3595)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.fromClause(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:720)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.query(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:576)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.selectStatement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:313)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker.statement(HqlSqlBaseWalker.java:261)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:266)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:141)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:115)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:77)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:153)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:553)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:662)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:23)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy105.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.SimpleJpaQuery.validateQuery(SimpleJpaQuery.java:87)
    ... 76 common frames omitted
```

With the solution proposed I got the same error

With this query I have also the same error (?!?)

```
 @Query("select us.priceAlertsTapas.tapa from User us ")
```

Here the User object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_user")
public class User implements Serializable, UserDetails {

...

@ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
        name="t_user_price_alert_tapa",
        joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="price_alert_tapa_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    private Set<PriceAlertTapa> priceAlertsTapas = new HashSet<>();
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_price_alert")
public class PriceAlert implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    public PriceAlert(int id) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
    }


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id; 

    private String name;

...

    }
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="t_price_alert_tapa")
public class PriceAlertTapa  implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;


    public PriceAlertTapa(PriceAlert priceAlert, Tapa tapa) {
        super();
        this.tapa = tapa;
        this.priceAlert = priceAlert;
    }

    private Tapa tapa;

    private PriceAlert priceAlert;
..
}
```

Comment: Your query return `us` which is a User but your list if of type `Tapa` you see that?

Comment: Can you post your entity classes and PriceAlert class?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I was getting this error as I was using table name in `@Query()`, but you have to use class name in `@Query()`:

Incorrect:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("from SHIPPING_DOC e where e.fulfillmentId in ?1")
List<ShippingDocumentsJsonEntity> deleteByFulfillmentIdIn(List<String> fulfillmentIds);
```

Correct:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query("from ShippingDocumentsJsonEntity e where e.fulfillmentId in ?1")
List<ShippingDocumentsJsonEntity> deleteByFulfillmentIdIn(List<String> fulfillmentIds);
```

Comment: Works well. Thank you.

Comment: @avinash kumar How to use Paginaiton with this query?
means take an example of below code

Transactional
Modifying
Query("from ShippingDocumentsJsonEntity e where e.fulfillmentId in ?1")
Page<List<ShippingDocumentsJsonEntity>> deleteByFulfillmentIdIn(List<String> fulfillmentIds);

So if i want to apply Page interface then what changes are required?

Comment: just to add on, this is because by default @Query() uses JPQL and if we want to use native SQL queries the we have to add nativeQuery = true to the @Query annotation

Answer (score 10):

Since priceAlertsTapas is Set you can't use dot-path.

```
@Query("select us.priceAlertsTapas.tapa from User us")
```

First you need to join it

```
@Query("select pat.tapa from User us join us.priceAlertsTapas pat")
```

Comment: @enPeris..ElgothdelaCiutat If you don't specify the order and tapas are different ones it might be Set both in the relationship and the result

Comment: @enPeris..ElgothdelaCiutat If my answer helped you could I accept the bounty, please?

Comment: sure, sorry :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have no reason to use a left (outer) join if your are only interested in the rightmost entity - although I'm not sure that this is the reason for which the validation of your query fails.

I would try this:

```
@Query("select tapa fom PriceAlertsTapas pat join pat.tapa tapa where pat.priceAlert = ?1")
List<Tapa> tapasByUserPriceAlert (PriceAlert pa);
```

If a given "tapa" can have multiple association to a "price alert" (eg one per user) then you will find it multiple times in your return `List`. The solution is either to change the return type to `Set<Tapa>` or to use `"select distinct...."` in your query.

If, on the other hand, your PriceAlertsTapas is a simple many-to-many association, it might be better to use the @ManyToMany JPA annotation, eventually with @JoinTable. See, for example, [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/).

Comment: I use the @ManyToMany relationship in the User entity with PriceAlertsTapas

Answer (score 0):

You have this exception because you have wrong select:

`us` is `User`

`us.priceAlertsTapas`  is `Set`

after that you truing to get `tapa` from it but `Set` don't have such field.

Comment: no, try to use `pat.tapa` instead of `us.priceAlertsTapas.tapa`

Answer (score 0):

We need to use class name instead of table name and field names instead of column names in query string. But if we are using property of nativeQuery=true we must use table and column names in query string.