# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration'

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I have created a maven module for implementing spring batch in our project. My aim is to export data from database table to CSV file (basing on a repository implemented in another maven module).

In my Spring boot main class I have the following:

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"com.test"})
@ComponentScan({"com.test"})
public class MainBatchApplication {
    public static void main(String args []){
        SpringApplication.run(MainBatchApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

The package `com.test`  is the path of our implemented UserRepository I want to use to get all users from database.

Once I inject the UserRepository in my Spring Batch created maven module and once I run the spring boot app. I got the following error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'batchConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List com.test.repositories.UserRepository.getFilteredByMonth(java.lang.String,java.util.Date,java.util.Date)!
```

The module where `com.test` if included in my batch maven module as dependency (pom.xml)

Comment: Share your Repository class also

Comment: @NicholasK Thanks for answering, Repository class is good i see as I used it in my service

Comment: You need to post your repository and especially your getFilteredByMonth method.  But likely your query is not legit JQL, as in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647630/validation-failed-for-query-for-method-jpql,  You probably need to mark your query as a native one.

Comment: @RobertMoskal i tried to comment the method getFiltredByMonth and i got another error with another repository that i din't used but in the same package where my used repository is. isn't womethong with the configuration ? is my componentScan annotation correct ?

Comment: You'll have to post the repository code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define configuration somewhere in your project with:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
 ....
}
```

Then you would be able to inject your Repository here for writers.

It would need some more bean definition. See: https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/ for examples