# Getting error with paging but working fine with List

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, pagination

I am working on a project which has two entities: Student and teacher.
It follows the @ManyToOne relationship. One Teacher can have multiple students. I am facing some difficulty while running the project.

Pageable page = PageRequest.of(pageNo, size)

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM TeacherEntity s JOIN FETCH s.student d WHERE s.student IN (:students) and s.deleted = false" +
            " ORDER BY s.createdAt DESC")
Page<TeacherEntity> findByStudent(@Param("students") Collection<StudentEntity> students, Pageable pageable);
```

I am getting this error "FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page " when I use paging.

When I do it without using paging like this,

```
@Query(value = "SELECT s FROM TeacherEntity s JOIN FETCH s.student d WHERE s.student IN (:students) and s.deleted = false" +
            " ORDER BY s.createdAt DESC")
List<TeacherEntity> findByStudentIn(@Param("students") 
Collection<StudentEntity> student);
```

, it is working fine. Can someone please tell me what is the mistake I am doing?

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'teacherRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Count query validation failed for method public abstract org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.pro.aks.repository.TeacherRepository.findByStudent(java.util.Collection,org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:176) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1827) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1265) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:334) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:624) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:612) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:51) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.onApplicationEvent(DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener.java:36) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.2.RELEASE.jar:2.3.2.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Are equals hashcode overridden on TeacherEntity ?

Comment: @SKumar Can you please tell what do u mean by Hashcode here?

Comment: so have you overriden equals method but not hashcode method ? Can you post your TeacherEntity to the question ?

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with it. Because code is working perfectly fine when I don't use pagination and use List

Comment: If you have not overriden both the methods, then it's fine. Otherwise, that can be some issue if you haven't defined them correctly. Paging will need to find some x number of records and that rely on those methods. Are you getting correct number of records in that List scenario ?

Comment: @SKumar Yes sir, I am getting correct number of records in the List scenario

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to print out the full stacktrace for checking the error: **Count query validation failed**

You need to define "countQuery" in your method "findByStudent". Check this link for the details: [Spring Data and Native Query with pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349930/spring-data-and-native-query-with-pagination)

Spring framework can't create the object because the method definition (annotation) is wrong.

**Technology behind:**
Spring framework will use the "countQuery" annotation (HQL) to generate the "Raw SQL" (SQL), if this information is missing, then Spring framework don't know how to count the data.

Comment: added the stacktrace

Comment: Refer to this link, change the SQL may be help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647630/validation-failed-for-query-for-method-jpql

Comment: Already checked, didn't help. The problem is why it is giving error while using paging and not when using List?

Comment: I have a suggestion, can you modify the SQL to the following simple SQL for testing? Let's test it together and find the root cause step by step: SELECT s FROM TeacherEntity s

Comment: Do you mean this simple query works but your original query does not?

Comment: I think this is happening because I am using Join fetch with pagination.

Comment: I have updated the detail in the answer, please check.