# Error creating bean with name 'registrationController'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I want to do code where `registration` can be done by spring security. After that I want to confirm the registered email address. The registration system is working well, but the problem is when I tried to confimarm the Token. I have got the following error, I don't know how to solve it. Error to create bean with name registrationController I have posted the structure of my project and the error, you will have to find the `controllerRegistartion` class and `RegistrationService` class.

**This is the entire erro**

```
    Error creating bean with name 'registrationController' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\RegistrationController.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\RegistrationService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\services\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmationTokenService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\token\ConfirmationTokenService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'confimationTokenRepository' defined in ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:917) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:582) ~[spring-context-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[spring-boot-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
    at ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.MinuteBricoPiApplication.main(MinuteBricoPiApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:64) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.4.3.jar:2.4.3]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'registrationService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\RegistrationService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\services\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmationTokenService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\token\ConfirmationTokenService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'confimationTokenRepository' defined in ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\services\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmationTokenService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\token\ConfirmationTokenService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'confimationTokenRepository' defined in ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 39 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'confirmationTokenService' defined in file [C:\Users\ilias\eclipse-workspace\MinuteBrico-pi\target\classes\ma\ac\emi\minutebrico\Registration\token\ConfirmationTokenService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'confimationTokenRepository' defined in ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'confimationTokenRepository' defined in ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation failed for query for method public abstract int ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfimationTokenRepository.updateConfirmedAt(java.lang.String,java.time.LocalDateTime)!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1786) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300) ~[spring-beans-5.3.4.jar:5.3.4]
```

**Project Structure**

[image]

**RegistrationController.java**

```
package ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(path ="registration")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationController {

    private final RegistrationService registrationService ;
    
    
    public RegistrationController(RegistrationService registrationService) {
        super();
        this.registrationService = registrationService;
    }


    @PostMapping
    public String register(@RequestBody RegistrationRequest request) {
        return registrationService.register(request);
    }
    
    
    //@GetMapping("/confirm")
    @GetMapping(path="confirm")
    public String confirm(@RequestParam("token")String token) {
        return registrationService.confirmToken(token);
    }
}
```

**RegistrationService.java**

```
package ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfirmationToken;
import ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token.ConfirmationTokenService;
import ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.models.AppUserRole;
import ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.models.User;
import ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.repository.EmailSender;
import ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.services.UserService;

@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RegistrationService {
    

    private final  UserService userService;
    private final  EmailValidator emailValidator;
    private final  ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService;
    private final  EmailSender emailSender;
    
    
    
    // s'il ya un problem
    public RegistrationService(UserService userService,
            EmailValidator emailValidator,
            ConfirmationTokenService confirmationTokenService,
            EmailSender emailSender
            )
    {
        super();
        this.userService = userService;
        this.emailValidator = emailValidator;
        this.confirmationTokenService = confirmationTokenService;
        this.emailSender = emailSender ;
        
    }

    public String register(RegistrationRequest request) {
        boolean isValidEmail = emailValidator.
                test(request.getEmail());
        if(!isValidEmail) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email is not valid");
        }
        String token = userService.SignUpUser(
                new User(
                         request.getFirstName(),
                         request.getLastName(),
                         request.getEmail(),
                         request.getPassword(),
                         AppUserRole.Client
                         )
                );
        String link = "http://localhost:8080/registration/confirm?token"+ token;
        emailSender.send(
                    request.getEmail(),
                    buildEmail(request.getFirstName(),link));
        return token;
    }

    @Transactional
    public String confirmToken(String token) {
        ConfirmationToken confirmationToken = confirmationTokenService
                .getToken(token)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                      new IllegalStateException("token not found")
                );
        
        if(confirmationToken.getConfirmedAt() != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("email alredy confirmed") ;
        }
        LocalDateTime expiredAt = confirmationToken.getExpiresAt();
        
        if(expiredAt.isBefore(LocalDateTime.now())) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("token expired");
        }
        confirmationTokenService.setConfirmedAt(token);
        userService.enableUser(// probeleme of getEmail ==> delete it from User.java
                confirmationToken.getUser().getEmail());
                
        return "Confirmed";
    }
    private String buildEmail(String name, String link) {
        return "<div style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;margin:0;color:#0b0c0c\">\n" +
                "\n" +
                "<span style=\"display:none;font-size:1px;color:#fff;max-height:0\"></span>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;min-width:100%;width:100%!important\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\">\n" +
                "    <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"100%\" height=\"53\" bgcolor=\"#0b0c0c\">\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "        <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;max-width:580px\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" align=\"center\">\n" +
                "          <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "            <td width=\"70\" bgcolor=\"#0b0c0c\" valign=\"middle\">\n" +
                "                <table role=\"presentation\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">\n" +
                "                  <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "                    <td style=\"padding-left:10px\">\n" +
                "                  \n" +
                "                    </td>\n" +
                "                    <td style=\"font-size:28px;line-height:1.315789474;Margin-top:4px;padding-left:10px\">\n" +
                "                      <span style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-weight:700;color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;vertical-align:top;display:inline-block\">Confirm your email</span>\n" +
                "                    </td>\n" +
                "                  </tr>\n" +
                "                </tbody></table>\n" +
                "              </a>\n" +
                "            </td>\n" +
                "          </tr>\n" +
                "        </tbody></table>\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody></table>\n" +
                "  <table role=\"presentation\" class=\"m_-6186904992287805515content\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;max-width:580px;width:100%!important\" width=\"100%\">\n" +
                "    <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" height=\"10\" valign=\"middle\"></td>\n" +
                "      <td>\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "                <table role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse\">\n" +
                "                  <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "                    <td bgcolor=\"#1D70B8\" width=\"100%\" height=\"10\"></td>\n" +
                "                  </tr>\n" +
                "                </tbody></table>\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" valign=\"middle\" height=\"10\"></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody></table>\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "\n" +
                "  <table role=\"presentation\" class=\"m_-6186904992287805515content\" align=\"center\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" style=\"border-collapse:collapse;max-width:580px;width:100%!important\" width=\"100%\">\n" +
                "    <tbody><tr>\n" +
                "      <td height=\"30\"><br></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" valign=\"middle\"><br></td>\n" +
                "      <td style=\"font-family:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:19px;line-height:1.315789474;max-width:560px\">\n" +
                "        \n" +
                "            <p style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;font-size:19px;line-height:25px;color:#0b0c0c\">Hi " + name + ",</p><p style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;font-size:19px;line-height:25px;color:#0b0c0c\"> Thank you for registering. Please click on the below link to activate your account: </p><blockquote style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;border-left:10px solid #b1b4b6;padding:15px 0 0.1px 15px;font-size:19px;line-height:25px\"><p style=\"Margin:0 0 20px 0;font-size:19px;line-height:25px;color:#0b0c0c\"> <a href=\"" + link + "\">Activate Now</a> </p></blockquote>\n Link will expire in 15 minutes. <p>See you soon</p>" +
                "        \n" +
                "      </td>\n" +
                "      <td width=\"10\" valign=\"middle\"><br></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "    <tr>\n" +
                "      <td height=\"30\"><br></td>\n" +
                "    </tr>\n" +
                "  </tbody></table><div class=\"yj6qo\"></div><div class=\"adL\">\n" +
                "\n" +
                "</div></div>";
    }

}
```

**the ConfirmationTokenRepository.java Interface**

```
    package ma.ac.emi.minutebrico.Registration.token;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface ConfimationTokenRepository extends JpaRepository<ConfirmationToken,Long>{

    Optional<ConfirmationToken> findByToken (String token);
    
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query("UPDATE ConfirmationToken c" +
           "SET c.confirmedAt = ?2 " +
            "WHERE c.token = ?1")
    int  updateConfirmedAt(String token, LocalDateTime confirmedAt);
    
}
```

Comment: The exception looks not being complete, it misses the last part. Can you please paste the full stacktrace?

Comment: @AllArgsConstructor
what is use of this annotation.

Comment: @AllArgsConstructor Generates an all-args constructor. An all-args constructor requires one argument for every field in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the exception you posted looks not complete, however, looking at that, I see that the issue is actually in the `ConfimationTokenRepository` class, which you haven't posted the code here, so I cannot make sure where the cause is.

Normally this happens when you have defined a method with a `@Query` annotation, which by default are validated by Spring according to JPA specification.

I suggest that you double check the queries that you have defined in your repository class, verify that they are well-formatted and you haven't missed any quoted space, charactes, conditions, etc...

If the query looks fine with you and the problem is the JPA validation itself, I think your question has got already an answer. Take a look at this and see if it helps: [Validation failed for query for method JPQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44647630/validation-failed-for-query-for-method-jpql).

**Edit:**
As I suspected, the issue is in the query you have defined in the class `ConfirmationTokenRepository` for method `updateConfirmedAt`. Here is the full String:

```
"UPDATE ConfirmationToken c" +
   "SET c.confirmedAt = ?2 " +
   "WHERE c.token = ?1"
```

you see that `c` and `SET` are actually attached one to each other, but that is quite hidden by the concatenation, so you might miss it due to the fact that you are concatenating two different internal String objects.
To fix the issue, just add a space there and it should work, in this way for example:

```
       "UPDATE ConfirmationToken c " +
       "SET c.confirmedAt = ?2 " +
       "WHERE c.token = ?1"
```

Comment: Mr @Marco I have added the ConfirmationTokenRepository.java

Comment: Mr @IliassAlilou I have edited the answer and added the fix in there.

Comment: You're very welcome. Would you mind accepting the answer? In this way it will be marked as resolved and can be useful for others who might have same issue in the future. Thanks.

Comment: of Course Mr @Marco